# Excel - Drag and repeat formula pattern series

Tags: excel, excel-formula, autofill

I am trying to replicate a pattern of formulas in excel but it's not appearing the way I expect but I'm looking for a solution.

I have the first 2 rows in a table defined and it has 4 columns

The formulas are as follows:

```
A1 =CONCATENATE(Scores!D11," (",Scores!F11,")")
B1 =Scores!AF11
C1 =Scores!AH11
D1 =Scores!AH15

A2 =CONCATENATE(Scores!D17," (",Scores!F17,")") 
B2 =Scores!AF17
C2 =Scores!AH17
D2 =Scores!AH21
```

I expected when I highlight the cells and dragged down that it would repeat the formula by adding 6 to all the value as shown above.

Is there an easy way to autofill the rows I need as I have to populate over 80 and possible more in the future.

Comment: Yes all the columns need to increment by 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use instead in A1:

`=CONCATENATE(INDEX(Scores!D:D,11+6*(ROWS($1:1)-1))," (",INDEX(Scores!F:F,11+6*(ROWS($1:1)-1)),")")`

then copy down as required, which has the additional benefit of avoiding volatile INDIRECT set-ups.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Indirect()` for the formulas to determine which row they are supposed to go after. Basing the logic off of the current row on which the formula resides:

In `A1`:

```
=Concatenate(Indirect("Scores!D" & (11 + (Row()-1)*6)), " (", Indirect("Scores!F" & (11 + (Row()-1)*6)), ")")
```

In `B1`:

```
=Indirect("Scores!AF" & (11 + (Row()-1)*6))
```

You can see what's happening more clearly in that `B1` example. We are dynamically determining the number `11` by using that formula `11 + (Row()-1)*6`. For `B1` the `ROW()` returns `0`, so the formula is `11+(0-1)*6` or `11`. That 11 is concatenated with `Scores!AF` and then `Indirect()` returns that back to the formula so it can then look up Scores!AF11 from the workbook and return it's value.

When you copy that formula down to `B2` the `ROW()` returns `2` and the formula then works out to `17`, which is your `B1` value + 6.

That's a few hops, skips, and jumps to get what you need, but the formula will copy down nicely and save you a lot of typing.